# Using setInterval, prepended value repeating. How to prepend once and stop?

Tags: jquery

Maybe I should do this server side but wanted to ask and see if there is a way to do this in JQuery first.

I have the following code

```
var refresh = setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "scroller.asp",
    success: function(data) { $("#scroll tbody").prepend(data); },
    dataType:'html'
   });
},10000);
```

For each interval, the server data is prepending the same row of data. How can I get only one prepended row of data and then have it stop unless the data is different?

Comment: Why don't you store the last value, compare, and append only if it's different ? What step in the process is hard to you ?

Comment: I already thought of that but if I store the last value, it will be overwritten by the next interval. Am I missing something?

Comment: What are the data ? A row of numbers ?

Comment: HTML. A single row of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you receive arrays of numbers, you can store the last value, compare, and append only if it's different :

```
(function(){
   var lastData = [];
   var refresh = setInterval(function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: "scroller.asp",
       success: function(data) {
           var identical = (lastData.length==data.length);
           if (identical) {
               for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                  if (data[i]!=lastData[i]) {
                    identical = false;
                    break;
                  }
               }
           }
           if (identical) return;
           lastData = data;
           $("#scroll tbody").prepend(data);
       },
       dataType:'html'
     });
   },10000);
})();
```

Of course you may easily adapt that to another type of data. For example with html :

```
(function(){
   var lastData = "";
   var refresh = setInterval(function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: "scroller.asp",
       success: function(data) {
           if (lastData == data) return;
           lastData = data;
           $("#scroll tbody").prepend(data);
       },
       dataType:'html'
     });
   },10000);
})();
```

Comment: Ahh.. The second example seems like it would work. Yeah, I see what you've done here.

Comment: Server side you mainly have 2 options : return a special short value meaning there's nothing when it didn't change. Or better use a push protocol like websocket (preferably through a library with fallbacks like socket.io).

Comment: Say, let me ask you a question about that. I'm worried about an overload on my server from all the AJAX requests. Would websockets prevent server overload?

Comment: Yes, it will be cleaner and saner. But a request every 10 seconds is nothing, even if you have hundreds of browsers, apart if your server doesn't cache and is very slow to fetch the data. The main advantage of using websockets to push data is the speed : you can have instant sending of the data from the source to the browser.

Comment: That's really cool. Can you recommend a good library for this? I have another app other than the one I'm currently on that would greatly benefit from this!

Comment: [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is the usual recommendation but it depends on what you're using server side (I hope it's not PHP, which is very bad at websocketing).

Comment: Actually, it is PHP. :(  Is there any other choice in my case?

Comment: If you can't get rid of PHP, you'd better use a good old pulling loop as you did. As long as you're not interested in fast client update, it's OK. It's also almost common to have an application in another technology (java,C#,node,go,etc.) for fast updates along an old application which is mainly PHP)

Comment: OK, thanks. By the way, I can't seem to get your second example working. What is this doing? `var identical = lastData == data.length` The data are still being repeated.

Comment: It's still prepending the same row. :/  Over and over and over

Comment: I got it, thank you. :)  Also, I really appreciate the advice on sockets. I'll look around for something that may be compatible with PHP.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit this, but I forgot to refresh your edit. lol.. Your edt worked out just fine. :)